# Actionscript 3: User input events not firing from children blit sprite objects

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, blit

Still programming an iPad game in Actionscript 3, I am encountering a problem that keeps me from advancing any further. I use blitting for animation, and as such, all my object use blitting for rendering. All objects are children of a game class which has a bitmapData canvas on which are rendered the game elements.

That's for how it should work. So far, there are no compilation or runtime errors, but for some reason I can't get any user input event from any object apart from the game itself. I have checked the event flow as well as the layering of the objects, but so far all I could find out is that for some reason the main canvas is the only element that can be targeted for events. Because players need to be able to touch them, two game elements are concerned: Twinkys and Racquets.

I have tried changing the layering of the elements, in order of instanciation and rendering, hiding some, changing event types (using mouse event instead of touch events) and toggling the `mouseEnabled` property of the game class with no positive result. All I can be sure of is that the game class is intercepting all events targeted at its children, making it impossible to play. I hope someone can see what I've done wrong.

Game class:

```
package Game
{
import Game.*;
import Game.Worlds.Level1.Level1;

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display3D.IndexBuffer3D;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

public class Game extends Sprite
{
    /** Hold each racquet so as to retrieve them when collision detection is needed. **/
    internal var racquetList:Vector.<Racquet>= new Vector.<Racquet>(2,true);
    /** Hold each Zwig so as to retrieve them when collision detection is needed. **/
    internal var zwigColliderList:Vector.<Collider>= new Vector.<Collider>(2,true);

    /** Object that contains the coordinates for the Twinkys in the counter. **/
    internal var twinkyScore0:Object= {firstX:727,firstY:950,secondX:710,secondY:911,
        thirdX:690,thirdY:872,fourthX:674,fourthY:840,
        fifthX:657,fifthY:808};
    internal var twinkyScore1:Object= {firstX:41,firstY:74,secondX:58,secondY:113,
        thirdX:78,thirdY:152,fourthX:94,fourthY:184,
        fifthX:111,fifthY:216};

    /** Speed decay coefficient. The closer to 1 the less speed decays. **/
    private var friction:Number= .96;
    /** Maximum speed cap for twinkys. The higher the number the grater the maximal speed. **/
    private var speedMax:Number= 10;

    /** Important positions for the placement of game elements.
     * LianaHeight is the height at which the liana on the players' HUDs is ending their zone and on which the racquet travels.
     * TwinkyHeight is the height at which the players stop controlling their Twinkys.
     * YMargin is the vertical margin for the Twinkys. Used to place them at the end of the tube when added.
     * XMargin is the horizontal margin for the Twinkys. Used to place them at the end of the tube when added. **/
    private var positions:Object= {LianaHeight:165,TwinkyHeight:265,YMargin:8.0,XMargin:200.0};

    private var _mRef:ZwigsIpad;
    Multitouch.inputMode= MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

    private var _Canvas:BitmapData= new BitmapData(ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right,ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom,false);
    private var _Background:Background;
    private var _HUD1:HUD;
    private var _HUD2:HUD;
    private var _Score:Score;
    private var _Zwig1:Zwig;
    private var _Zwig2:Zwig;
    private var _Racquet1:Racquet;
    private var _Racquet2:Racquet;
    private var _Twinky1:Twinky;
    private var _Twinky2:Twinky;

    /** Create the first level. It will create the stage and add the background, HUDs, Zwigs, Racquets and Twinkys, and manages the game until the end. **/
    public function Game(m:ZwigsIpad)
    {
        this._mRef= m;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

        // Add game canvas on which all assets are rendered
        addChild(new Bitmap(this._Canvas));

        // Get informations from Level1
        // LATER make it dependant from what level was chosen (switch case)
        this.positions.LianaHeight= Level1.LIANA_HEIGHT;
        this.positions.TwinkyHeight= Level1.TWINKY_HEIGHT;
        this.positions.YMargin= Level1.TWINKY_MARGIN_Y;
        this.positions.XMargin= Level1.TWINKY_MARGIN_X;
        this.friction= Level1.TWINKY_FRICTION;
        this.speedMax= Level1.TWINKY_SPEED_MAX;

        // Add background
        this._Background= new Background(this._Canvas,0);
        addChild(this._Background);

        // Add HUD
        this._HUD1= new HUD(this._Canvas);
        this._HUD2= new HUD(this._Canvas,true,1);
        addChild(this._HUD1);
        addChild(this._HUD2);

        // Add scoring
        this._Score= new Score(this,this._mRef);
        addChild(this._Score);

        // Add zwigs
        this._Zwig1= new Zwig(this._Canvas);
        this._Zwig2= new Zwig(this._Canvas,true,1);
        addChild(this._Zwig1);
        addChild(this._Zwig2);

        // Add zwigs' colliders to vector
        this.zwigColliderList[0]= this._Zwig1.collider;
        this.zwigColliderList[1]= this._Zwig2.collider;

        // Add racquets
        this._Racquet1= new Racquet(this.positions,this._Canvas);
        this._Racquet2= new Racquet(this.positions,this._Canvas,false,1);
        addChild(this._Racquet1);
        addChild(this._Racquet2);

        // Add racquets to vector
        this.racquetList[0]= this._Racquet1;
        this.racquetList[1]= this._Racquet2;

        // Add twinkys
        this._Twinky1= new Twinky(this,this._Score,this,this.positions,this.friction,this.speedMax,this._Canvas,0);
        this._Twinky2= new Twinky(this,this._Score,this,this.positions,this.friction,this.speedMax,this._Canvas,1,false,1);
        addChild(this._Twinky1);
        addChild(this._Twinky2);

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,renderLevel);
    }

    private function renderLevel(e:Event):void
    {
        this._Canvas.lock();

        this._Background.render();
        this._HUD1.render();
        this._HUD2.render();
        this._Score.render();
        this._Zwig1.render();
        this._Zwig2.render();
        this._Racquet1.render();
        this._Racquet2.render();
        this._Twinky1.render();
        this._Twinky2.render();

        this._Canvas.unlock();
    }
}
}
```

Twinky class:

```
package Game
{
import Game.Game;
import Game.Score;

import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

/** The Twinky is the main player controlled class. **/
internal class Twinky extends Sprite
{
    private var _mRef:Game;
    private var _sRef:Score;
    private var player:uint;

    Multitouch.inputMode= MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    private var _touchMoveID:int= 0;
    private var _speedX:Number= 0;
    private var _speedY:Number= 0;
    private var xOffset:Number;
    private var yOffset:Number;
    private var currentX:Number;
    private var currentY:Number;
    private var oldX:Number;
    private var oldY:Number;
    private var dragging:Boolean= false;
    private var launched:Boolean= false;
    private var _point:Point= new Point();

    private var positions:Object;
    private var friction:Number;
    private var speedMax:Number;
    private var canvas:BitmapData;
    private var isAtBottom:Boolean;
    private var skin:uint;

    private var _image:BitmapData;
    private var _idleArray:Array= new Array();
    private var i:uint= 0;

    // Yellow twinky
    [Embed (source= "Assets/Players/twinky1.png")]
    private const Twinky1idle:Class;
    private var _twinky1idleArray:Array;
    // Red twinky
    [Embed (source= "Assets/Players/twinky2.png")]
    private const Twinky2idle:Class;
    private var _twinky2idleArray:Array;

    private const twinkyWidth:uint= 64;
    private const twinkyHeight:uint= 64;

    private var t1i001:Rectangle= new Rectangle(0,0,twinkyWidth,twinkyHeight);
    private var t2i001:Rectangle= new Rectangle(0,0,twinkyWidth,twinkyHeight);

    /** Create Twinky. Twinkys must be flicked to the same colored Zwig to
     * feed it and die when they lost momentum. **/
    public function Twinky(daddy:Game,score:Score,m:Game,positions:Object,friction:Number,speedMax:Number,canvas:BitmapData,player:uint,isAtBottom:Boolean=true,skin:uint=0)
    {
        // Get score and game object reference
        this._sRef= score;
        this._mRef= daddy;

        this.positions= positions;
        this.friction= friction;
        this.speedMax= speedMax;
        this.canvas= canvas;
        this.player= player;
        this.isAtBottom= isAtBottom;
        this.skin= skin;

        this._twinky1idleArray= [t1i001];
        this._twinky2idleArray= [t2i001];

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init,false,0,true);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

        // Get skin
        switch (this.skin)
        {
            case 0:
                this._image= new this.Twinky1idle().bitmapData;
                this._idleArray= this._twinky1idleArray;
            break;

            case 1:
                this._image= new this.Twinky2idle().bitmapData;
                this._idleArray= this._twinky2idleArray;
            break;

            default:
                this._image= new this.Twinky1idle().bitmapData;
                this._idleArray= this._twinky1idleArray;
            break;
        }

        // Give position
        if (this.isAtBottom)
        {
            this.x= this.positions.XMargin;
            this.y= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - this.positions.YMargin;

            // Animate entrance
            TweenMax.from(this,1,{x:this.x-70,y:this.y-12,rotation:-180,alpha:.5});
        }
        else
        {
            this.x= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right - this.positions.XMargin;
            this.y= this.positions.YMargin;

            // Animate entrance
            TweenMax.from(this,1,{x:this.x+70,y:this.y+12,rotation:-180,alpha:.5});
        }

        this._point.x= this.x;
        this._point.y= this.y;

        aText.appendText("\n position: "+this.x+" "+this.y);

        // Detect touched
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,touchDown);
        // Always detect untouched
        this._mRef.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,touchUp);
        // Always do kinetics
        this._mRef.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,freeMove);
    }

    /** Render the Twinky at its current coordinates by redrawing it. **/
    internal function render():void
    {
        this._point.x= this.x - this._idleArray[i].width * .5;
        this._point.y= this.y - this._idleArray[i].height * .5;

        this.canvas.copyPixels(this._image,this._idleArray[0/*i*/],this._point);

        // When idle finished restart, else pursue with animation
        /*if (i==this._idleArray.length - 1)
            i= 0;
        else
            i++;*/
    }

    // TWINKY AND RACQUET DO NOT DETECT TOUCH EVENTS because the main canvas covers them
    // Start dragging when touched
    private function touchDown(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        aText.appendText("\n Twinky touched!");

        if (this._touchMoveID != 0)
            return;

        this._touchMoveID= e.touchPointID;
        this.dragging= true;
        // Get the mouse's offset on the object
        this.xOffset= e.localX;
        this.yOffset= e.localY;

        this._mRef.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,touchMove);
    }

    private function touchMove(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        if (e.touchPointID != this._touchMoveID)
            return;

        // Move twinky to where the mouse is
        this.x= e.stageX - this.xOffset;
        this.y= e.stageY - this.yOffset;

        // Don't go farther than borders
        if (this.x <= this.width * .5)
        {
            this.x= (this.width * .5) + .1;
        }

        if (this.x >= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right - (this.width * .5))
        {
            this.x= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right - (this.width * .5) - .1;
        }

        if (this.y <= this.height * .5)
        {
            this.y= (this.height * .5) + .1;
        }

        if (this.y >= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - (this.height * .5))
        {
            this.y= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - (this.height * .5) - .1;
        }

        // Be undraggable if zone is left
        if (this.isAtBottom)
        {
            if (this.y < (ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - this.positions.TwinkyHeight))
            {
                this._touchMoveID= 0;
                this.dragging= false;

                this._mRef.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,touchMove);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.y > this.positions.TwinkyHeight)
            {
                this._touchMoveID= 0;
                this.dragging= false;

                this._mRef.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,touchMove);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Refresh coordinates for display
        this._point.x= this.x;
        this._point.y= this.y;

        e.updateAfterEvent();
    }

    private function touchUp(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        if (e.touchPointID != this._touchMoveID)
            return;

        this._touchMoveID= 0;
        this.dragging= false;

        this._mRef.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,touchMove);
    }

    private function freeMove(e:Event):void
    {
        // Be undraggable if liana crossed
        if (this.isAtBottom)
        {
            if (this.y < (ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - this.positions.TwinkyHeight))
            {
                this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,touchDown);
                this._mRef.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,touchUp);
                this.dragging= false;
                this.launched= true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.y > this.positions.TwinkyHeight)
            {
                this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,touchDown);
                this._mRef.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,touchUp);
                this.dragging= false;
                this.launched= true;
            }
        }

        // Move the twinky and calculate its speed if player is dragging it 
        if (this.dragging)
        {
            aText.appendText("\n Twinky dragged!");
            this.oldX= currentX;
            this.oldY= currentY;
            currentX= this.x;
            currentY= this.y;

            // Calculate speed in X and Y axis
            this._speedX= this.currentX - this.oldX;
            this._speedY= this.currentY - this.oldY;

            // Cap maximal speed
            if (this._speedX > this.speedMax)
                this._speedX= this.speedMax;

            if (this._speedY > this.speedMax)
                this._speedY= this.speedMax;
        }
        // Otherwise move the twinky using its speed
        else
        {
            this.x+= this._speedX;
            this.y+= this._speedY;
        }

        // Detect collision with zwigs
        for (i= 0 ; i < this._mRef.zwigColliderList.length ; i++)
        {
            var cemp:Collider= this._mRef.zwigColliderList[i] as Collider;
            if (this.hitTestObject(cemp))
            {
                this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,touchDown);
                this._mRef.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,touchUp);
                this._mRef.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,freeMove);
                this._sRef.die(this,this.player,true,i);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Detect collision with borders: left border
        if (this.x <= this.width / 2)
        {
            // Don't go any further
            this.x= (this.width / 2) + .1;
            // Reverse speed to bounce
            this._speedX*= -1;
        }
        // Right border
        if (this.x >= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right - (this.width / 2))
        {
            this.x= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right - (this.width / 2) - .1;
            this._speedX*= -1;
        }
        // Top border
        if (this.y <= this.height / 2)
        {
            this.y= (this.height / 2) + .1;
            this._speedY*= -1;
        }
        // Bottom border
        if (this.y >= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - (this.height / 2))
        {
            this.y= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - (this.height / 2) - .1;
            this._speedY*= -1;
        }

        // Detect collision with racquets
        for (var i:uint= 0 ; i < this._mRef.racquetList.length ; i++)
        {
            var temp:Racquet= this._mRef.racquetList[i] as Racquet;
            if (this.hitTestObject(temp))
            {
                this._speedY*= -1;
                this.y+= this._speedY;
            }
        }

        // Speed decay
        this._speedX*= this.friction;
        this._speedY*= this.friction;

        // Set speed to 0 if speed is smaller than .5
        if (Math.abs(this._speedX) < .5) this._speedX= 0;
        if (Math.abs(this._speedY) < .5) this._speedY= 0;

        // If speed is null and it has been launched, kill twinky
        if (this._speedX == 0 && this._speedY == 0 && this.launched)
        {
            this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,touchDown);
            this._mRef.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,touchUp);
            this._mRef.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,freeMove);
            TweenMax.to(this, 1.5, {alpha:0, ease:Linear.easeNone});
            this._sRef.die(this,this.player);
            return;
        }

        // Refresh coordinates for display
        this._point.x= this.x;
        this._point.y= this.y;
    }
}
}
```

Racquet class:

```
package Game
{
import Game.Worlds.Level1.Level1;

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

internal class Racquet extends Sprite
{
    Multitouch.inputMode= MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    private var _touchMoveID:int= 0;
    private var xOffset:Number;
    private var dragging:Boolean= false;

    private var positions:Object;
    private var canvas:BitmapData;
    private var isAtBottom:Boolean;
    private var skin:uint;

    private var _image:BitmapData;
    private var _point:Point= new Point();

    // Yellow racquet
    [Embed (source= "Assets/Players/racq1.png")]
    private const Racquet1:Class;
    // Red racquet
    [Embed (source= "Assets/Players/racq2.png")]
    private const Racquet2:Class;

    public function Racquet(positions:Object,canvas:BitmapData,isAtBottom:Boolean=true,skin:uint=0)
    {
        this.positions= positions;
        this.canvas= canvas;
        this.isAtBottom= isAtBottom;
        this.skin= skin;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init,false,0,true);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

        // Get skin
        switch (this.skin)
        {
            case 0:
                //this._image= new R.Racquet1().bitmapData;
                this._image= new this.Racquet1().bitmapData;
            break;

            case 1:
                //this._image= new R.Racquet2().bitmapData;
                this._image= new this.Racquet2().bitmapData;
            break;

            default:
                this._image= new this.Racquet1().bitmapData;
            break;
        }

        // Give position
        if (this.isAtBottom)
        {
            this.x= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.centerX;
            this.y= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.bottom - this.positions.LianaHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            this.x= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.centerX;
            this.y= this.positions.LianaHeight;
        }

        this._point.x= this.x;
        this._point.y= this.y;

        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,touchDown,false,0,true);
        this.parent.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,touchUp,false,0,true);
    }

    internal function render():void
    {
        this._point.x= this.x - this._image.rect.width * .5;
        this._point.y= this.y - this._image.rect.height * .5;

        this.canvas.copyPixels(this._image,this._image.rect,this._point);
    }

    private function touchDown(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        aText.appendText("\n Racquet touched!");
        if(this._touchMoveID != 0)
            return;

        this._touchMoveID= e.touchPointID;

        this.xOffset= e.localX;
        this.parent.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,touchMove,false,0,true);
    }

    private function touchMove(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        if(e.touchPointID != this._touchMoveID)
            return;

        Multitouch.inputMode= MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        this._point.x= e.stageX - this.xOffset;

        if (this._point.x <= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.left + (this._image.width*.5))
            this._point.x= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.left + (this._image.width*.5);
        else if (this._point.x >= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right - (this._image.width*.5)) 
            this._point.x= ZwigsIpad.BORDERS.right - (this._image.width*.5);
    }

    private function touchUp(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        if(e.touchPointID != this._touchMoveID)
            return;

        this._touchMoveID= 0;
        this.parent.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,touchMove);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touch events will only fire when you touch a sprite's graphics. But all your graphics are drawn onto a single bitmap so your various sprites have nothing to interact with.

Flash provides a display list and does a good job of rendering it, so you shouldn't need to build your own complicated structures like this.

You should consider making each sprite contain its own graphics and things will just work out easier. If performance is a huge concern, I suggest getting it working first, and then play around with different optimisation strategies afterwards (e.g. cacheAsBitmap, clipping/scrolling with scrollRect etc.)

Comment: Of course... Thank you for the help, I shall be more attentive next time I go about this.